# How To Query Mongoose Database With Specific Time Range

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I have an order model and I want to fetch all orders that are created at last month to current date. Like receiving all orders from 1 may, 2021 to 1 jun 2021.

My database modal has `{timestamps: true}` option which adds `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields.

Order.js

```
const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    billingAddress: { type: Object, required: true },
    deliveryAddress: { type: Object, required: true },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    seller: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Shop",
    },
    Product: {
      product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product" },
      color: String,
      quantity: Number,
    },
    invoiceId: { type: String, required: true },
    paymentIntentId: { type: String, required: true },
    totalAmount: { type: Number, required: true },
    groupId: { type: String, required: true },
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: [
        "waitingConfirmation",
        "confirmed",
        "cancelRequest",
        "cancelled",
        "packing",
        "shipped",
        "delivered",
      ],
      default: "waitingConfirmation",
    },
    note: String,
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

When I do this to fetch last month's data it works

```
const lastMonthOrders = await Order.find({
    $and: [
      { seller: req.shop.id },
      {
        createdAt: {
          $gte: new Date(2021, 4, 1),
          $lt: new Date(2021, 5, 1),
        },
      },
    ],
  });
```

But I want my dates to be dynamic so I tried this

```
  let today = new Date();
  let lastMonth = new Date(
    today.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 1) - 60 * 60 * 1000
  );

const lastMonthOrders = await Order.find({
    $and: [
      { seller: req.shop.id },
      {
        createdAt: {
          $gte: lastMonth,
          $lt: today,
        },
      },
    ],
  });
```

timestamps in my model look like this, and their data type is Date:

```
createdAt: 2021-06-02T10:20:26.984+00:00,
updatedAt: 2021-06-02T10:21:28.432+00:00
```

The code above doesnt work. It returns an empty object. How to fetch data from a specific time range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [setMonth method](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) actually **modifies** the date, meaning `today` has now the same month as `lastMonth`, leaving a gap of only an hour between the two variables.

Try going with this code below, although it's a little weird:

```
const lastMonth = new Date();
lastMonth.setMonth(lastMonth.getMonth() - 1);
const today = new Date(new Date() - 60*60*1000);
```

Comment: Note, this takes the current time rather than midnight. You may have to adjust the time values.

Comment: True, I just took OPs code and assumed this was what he wanted but it might very well need adjusting

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library:

```
const lastMonthOrders = await Order.find({
    $and: [
      { seller: req.shop.id },
      {
        createdAt: {
          $gte: moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month').toDate(),
          $lt: moment().startOf('day').toDate(), 
          // or $lte: moment().subtract(1, 'day').endOf('day').toDate(),
        },
      },
    ],
  });
```

Comment: Although I would normally suggest this as well, if OP has no further business with dates I wouldn't recommend installing a package just for this. Also, see this https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals, it depends see https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs/issues/105 I always suggest moment.js if you have to work with dates - of course, it is just another solution.

Comment: Of course, there will always be cases when libraries are almost essential. I just wanted to point that it is not *always* necessary :)